# Allow external domains to use my nameserver without using BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind

Is it possible to allow users to point their domains to my nameservers from their domain provider, e.g. GoDaddy, 123-reg, etc. For example, they enter my nameservers: `ns1.domain.com`, `ns2.domain.com` into the set nameservers panel.

But when I go to my new domain that hasn't been configured with BIND on my server, Firefox says that the server cannot be found.

When I do a DNS lookup, the domains have my nameservers and the IP of the nameservers, but doesn't take me to my server. I already have a domain which is configured with BIND, but I want to allow other domains that are not mine to be able to connect to my nameservers without me configuring the domain with BIND, or is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely... I do this all the time.  Although you're mixing up a program with a protocol.  "Bind" is a program... (one of the most popular DNS servers out there) how you configure it is another subject entirely.

Almost every registrar will allow you to change your name-server records to point to another name server (yours perhaps) but you must have records at your end with the appropriate records.  DNS records are, unfortunately/fortunately, cached by almost every ISP in the world, and unfortunately records can take an exorbitant amount of time to filter through all the caching servers out there... which is why you might have had issues.  Without more info, can't be sure.  From there, it's just a simple matter of updating your name servers with the correct addresses & you're done.

Answer (score 1):

So you user have a domain, say user.com. This user.com have your nameservers ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com.

Now someone want to visit www.user.com. It first asks .com servers  "which servers should I use to find www.user.com address ?", and gets reply - "use nsX.domain.com" now it goes to ns1.domain.com and asks it "do you know address of www.user.com ?". Your BIND answers "I have no idea what is user.com". Done.

**You must add separate zone for each user domain in your BIND.**

OR

Your users may use their registrar DNS server and either configure CNAME or DNAME records to point to your **domain** (domain, not nameserver). This approach have problems as it's not OK to have CNAME for the zone apex (naked domain).

OR

Your users may use their registrar DNS server and configure DNS records same way as you configure it in your zone.

Comment: Alternatively, you could run a nameserver that had been modified to return whatever information you want. If you know what you're doing, you can modify `bind` to return a specific set of A records for any domains that weren't specifically configured but had your server listed as a nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

an example:

```
dig microsoft.com
```

[image]

As we can see, microsoft.com domain name 'is hosted' on the nsX.msft.net DNS servers. The ns1.msft.com name server could host not only microsoft.com namespace, but other namespaces (other zones) too (i.e. trees.com, cats.com, houses.com).
In the example I've provided, your DNS server is like the msft.com nameserver.

Note also, that the DNS server for microsoft.com zone doesn't have to be hosted as a subdomain of microsoft.com (i.e. as ns1.microsoft.com). Though, this is possible (with the use of glue A RRs). The DNS server domain name can be entirely different than the domain namespaces (zone files) the server hosts! (i.e. DNS server domain name: ns1.msft.net, domain namespace hosted: microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

Yess, if you want to have your `bind` server other domains you must add them as additional zones.  This will require reconfiguring your bind server.

The simplest configuration is where your server is a slave to another server where the master copy of the domain is maintained.  In this case your server will be a secondary server.

If your server is to be the master you will need to configure the entries for the zone, and ensure the zone is configured with at least one secondary server.

If you only want to server content for them, they can configure their own DNS servers to point to your server.  You will likely need to configure the services you are providing to be aware of the new domain(s) they are serving.

Answer (score 0):

No, the domains won't work until you configure them in BIND on your side. When they provide your hostname as NS records for their domains to the domain registry, all DNS requests will be routed to your server.

But your server must know how to answer them. And BIND can answer only those zones which it has configured. If configuring BIND is too difficult for you, try using database backend or some other nameserver software. Best would be if the other people can notify you that they have created a new domain and you just add it to your configuration. I don't think you will be adding many domains each month.

But if yes, you can try to automate it. Set BIND to log all received queries, then for example every hour let script analyze the queries, filter only those for which BIND didn't know the answer (should be SERVFAIL), run whois to be sure the domain actually points to your DNS server and add the domain to BIND. Then each new domain will work in 1 hour after the first request hits your server.